# Set ftp service in www folder for several seperate users

Tags: webserver, vsftpd

I have a web server( CENTOS 7 ) with some virtual hosts. I want to let some users upload their own files in their own www folders.

It means for each [apache] user they have their own folder. For example `user1` should have access to `/www/user1` and for `user2` access only to `/www/user2`.

So the question is, how should I prevent `user1` being able to browse to `user2`'s folder, and the same thing for to `user2`! and also no problems happen for [apache] and [php-fpm] !

Answer (score 0):

Is your web server running on Windows or Linux? when Windows, dit you try filezilla server? its easy and works fine. It is not recommend for professional using (for rent webspace or something)

Comment: the server is centos 7